# Rails design urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have this url structure:
`get 'categories/:pretty_name' => 'static_pages#categories'`

I did it for seo purposes. And for better user experience.

But I see that stackoveflow uses different structure for urls.In my case it will be something like this:

`get 'categories/:category_id/:pretty_name' => 'static_pages#categories'`

So I wonder will second approach (where we find category by id and just show `pretty_name` for user and seo after second `/` character will be faster ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case `pretty_name` must be a primary key to your resource (ie no duplicates, your search will use this field).

In the other case, the category id is present in the URI and `pretty_name` is your appended for aesthetic or SEO uses. This approach is more flexible IMO since it decouples the primary key.

Comment: will it be faster?=)